# Create unique URL in PHP for each entry

Tags: php

So i am trying to create independent web pages via PHP for practice im trying to learn.

What i want to do is to create unique URLs for each entry on my site.

Lets say my website is simple, it just asks the user to enter a name and records it to the database, and creates a unique URL for that user so he can go to his url and view his name.

I am looking to create a URL for each user lets say upto 8 characters `a-z A-Z 0-9` that would look like `url.com/uI53841a`

So if John goes to create a website it creates a url he can visit `url.com/uI53841a` for example.

My database would look like this below:

```
create table if not exists `entry` (
    `uniqueURL` VARCHAR(8),
    `name` VARCHAR(16),
    primary key (`uniqueURL`)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

How would i go about generating a unique ID for each person who submits their name to my site? And how do i go about making sure there are never any duplicates?

I am new to PHP and trying to learn, i see you can create md5 hashses but how can you randomize that and check theres no duplicates?

Comment: php has a unique id function, as does MySQL.

Comment: Generation is easy and there are multiple approaches. You may look into the PHP function: [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: @BrandonWhite he never said random, just unique

Comment: @Dagon I must've misread it. Whoops. Edited, thanks.

Comment: could always just use the id from an auto incremented field -its kind of the common approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout this [library](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php).

Small snippet from docs:

```
<?php

$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids();

$id = $hashids->encode(1, 2, 3);
$numbers = $hashids->decode($id);

var_dump($id, $numbers);
```

More info from [official site](http://hashids.org/php/).

P.S.

With primary key contrait for `uniqueUrl` you may check the result of insert with php. If it fails, it means that constrait is violated.

You may simply generate url based on other unique string, for example use raw `id` as url (as Dagon said in comments to the answer). But you should use aforementioned lib if you do not want to expose your database ids to the user (it's quote from github).

Comment: This is interesting i will surely check this out!

Comment: This is great! I been playing with it and its just what i needed, i just need to create something that will check against the database and rando it even more if its duplicate right? Which im sure is a very small chance

Comment: sure go for the overkill approach :-)

Comment: @sonicboom, yes, your need to build url based on unique string. I'v updated the answer.

Comment: @Dagon, I'v added notice about simple using id as url

Answer (score 0):

Heres one i found and worked on a little but which also works well!

```
function keygen()
{
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $chars .= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $chars .= "0123456789";
    while (1) {
        $key = '';
        srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $key .= substr($chars, (rand() % (strlen($chars))), 1);
        }
        break;
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Comment: I like your script and this is more or less what I was looking for. You posted it here 5 years ago. Do you have any experience regarding _collision_?